# ASP.NET Core Entity Framework call stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using ASP.NET Core Entity Framework and I would like to call a simple stored procedure.

I created the stored procedure in my migrations like this:

```
public partial class spGetAvailableCourses : Migration
{
    protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
    {
        var sp = @"CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetAvailableCourses]
            AS
            BEGIN
                SELECT COUNT(courses.Enrolled) FROM Courses WHERE Courses.Capacity > Courses.Enrolled;
            END";

        migrationBuilder.Sql(sp);
    }
```

I can call the stored procedure in SQL Server with the following command.

```
EXEC dbo.GetAvailableCourses
```

But when I try and call the stored procedure in in my `ICourseRepository`, it doesn't work, I get minus one returned.

Can someone please tell me the correct of calling the stored procedure? Thanks

```
public class CourseRepository : ICourseRepository
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public CourseRepository(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
   
    public Task<CoursesAvailableCount> CoursesAvailableCount()
    { 
        var ss = _context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("GetAvailableCourses");
        return null;
    }
```

I also tried

```
    public async Task<CoursesAvailableCount> CoursesAvailableCount()
    {
        var s = await _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommandAsync("GetAvailableCourses");
    }
```

Comment: check https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/working-with-stored-procedure-in-ef-core.aspx

Comment: It says "Result must be an entity type. This means that a stored procedure must return all the columns of the corresponding table of an entity." Does this mean its not possible to do it since i am returning an integer?

Comment: `ExecuteSqlRaw` returns the number of affected rows. It is the wrong method to call for a count result.

Comment: Why not use a pure EF lambda or linq statement instead? That is very easy to craft based on your sql code in the question.

Comment: As a side note: Should you keep the SP then I would rename `GetAvailableCourses` to `GetAvailableCourseCount` as I would expect a list of courses from `GetAvailableCourses` if I knew nothing else about that SP other than the name.

Comment: Try _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("GetAvailableCourses"); instead of ExecuteSqlRaw.

Comment: I know you can do with using linq very easily but the requirement is to use a storage procedure. I will rename it to your suggestion.

Comment: @noobprogrammer - that also returns the number of affected rows but this api endpoint is also marked as obsolete in the MS documentation.

Comment: @Igor do you have any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: You probably just have to do this manually with ado.net (DbConnection and DbCommand)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to the ExecuteSqlCommand method, the DbContext.Database property provides an API that allows you to perform ADO.NET operations directly. The GetDbConnection method returns a DbConnection object representing the context's underlying connection. From that point, you can revert to the familiar ADO.NET APIs:

```cs
using (var command = _context.Database.GetDbConnection ().CreateCommand ())
{
   command.CommandText = "SP_NAME";
   command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   _context.Database.OpenConnection ();
   using (var result = command.ExecuteReader ())
   {
      if (result.HasRows)
      {
         result.Read ();
         var x = result.GetInt32 (0); // x = your sp count value
      }
   }
}
```

EDIT (extension example):

```
public static class EfCoreExtensions
{
    public static int? Execute_SingleValue_SP_AsInt(this AppDbContext context,string SpName)
    {
        using (var command = context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = SpName;
            command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            context.Database.OpenConnection();
            using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (result.HasRows)
                {
                    result.Read();
               var x = result.GetInt32(0); // x = your sp count value
                    return x;
                }
            return null;
            }
        
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks AliReza. That works. I have never used ADO.Net before but it is there a better way of writing result.hasRow? I will read up on it. also should i do a finally i close for the dbconnection?

Comment: EntityFramework Core does not have `SqlQuery` function so this is your only way to handle custom SPs that can't map to an entity.
btw nothing is wrong with using ADO directly. EF is using this internally.
you can create an Extention method and use it easily.

Comment: Last question would you recommed using the command.ExecuteReaderAsync() instead of the command.ExecuteReader?

Comment: yes, I always use Async functions when i have a possible blocking task.

Comment: you Asked about HasRow, I recommend watching this video if you are not familiar to DataReaderObject 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyApEHLvmQU

Answer (score 3):

For .net core 3.1, using stored procedures with parameters. Use the below code. It works for me. Enjoy!!!

```
using (var command = DbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "Users_SP";
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(“@usernme”, username));
                    command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TransDate", DateTime.Now));
                    DbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
                    using (var result = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (result.HasRows)
                        {
                            while (result.Read())
                            {
                                response = Convert.ToString(result["Amount"]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```